# json_decode in php

Tags: php, json

I want to use json_decode to this json file but something is going wrong. It was working fine a few days ago but now returns NULL.

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://opendata.diavgeia.gov.gr/api/decisions?org=eot&output=json'; 


function works2($url) 
{ 
   $opts = array( 
     'http'=>array( 
       'method'=>"GET", 
       'header'=>"Connection:Keep-Alive\r\nAccept:*/*\r\n" 
     ) 
   ); 

   $context = stream_context_create($opts); 
   $retstr = file_get_contents($url,false,$context); 
   return $retstr; 
} 


var_dump(json_decode(works2($url)));
?>
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading json in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568135/reading-json-in-php)

Comment: Print `$retstr` after you retrieve it and see what you actually get from the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I used a JSON validator and the url seems to provide an INVALID JSON

try using jsonList to validate the URL here http://jsonlint.com/

I get

```
 Parse error on line 822:
 ...         "subject": "Ματαίωση του πρόχει
 -----------------------^
 Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

If the URL provides a proper JSON string your code should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help,
This is what i found. The json is broken from the server. I hope to be fixed soon.

Comment: Yup. You could clean up the json till wherever errors don't come up and use it if you want!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `json_decode` stopped working for you. It's rather server response. Did you print $retstr to make sure it's not empty or broken?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
This is what i found. The json is broken from the server. I hope to be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

works2 result is ok.
Maybe the json encoded content is too big or (probably) contains unwanted characters or a malformed sequence.
Take a look to default opendata output. It is xml format, but far long to download.